# Tabbed interface using jQuery, cannot make 'current' tab take opacitiy setting

Tags: jquery, html, css, opacity, tabbed-interface

I have adapted a jQuery tabbed interface tutorial to create an interface for viewing some images. The active tab should have an opacity of 1, but with the code I am using the 'current' class is assigned to the 'a' of the tab when clicked, but the opacity does not change, and remains at .3.

I am hoping I can achieve this effect without using the css opacity settings so that it will work with browsers that don't support this. I am very new to Jquery any help would be much appreciated.

```
        // Initialize.
function init_tabs() {

// Does element exist?
if (!$('ul.tabs').length) {

// If not, exit.
return;
}

// Reveal initial content area(s).
$('div.tab_content_wrap').each(function() {
$(this).find('div.tab_content:first').show();
});

$('ul.tabs a').css({ opacity: .3 });
$('ul.tabs a.current').css({ opacity: 1 });

$('ul.tabs a:not(.current)').hover(
function () {
$(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
},
function () {
$(this).fadeTo("fast", .3);
}
);

// Listen for click on tabs.
$('ul.tabs a').click(function() {

// If not current tab.
if (!$(this).hasClass('current')) {

// Change the current indicator.
$(this).addClass('current').css({opacity: 1}).parent('li').siblings('li')
.find('a.current').removeClass('current').css({opacity: .3}),


// Show target, hide others.
$($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(300).siblings('div.tab_content').hide();
}

// Nofollow.
this.blur();
return false;
});
 }

// Kick things off.
$(document).ready(function() {
init_tabs();
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be this code:

```
$('ul.tabs a:not(.current)').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).fadeTo("fast", .3);
    }
);
```

You are setting hovers on the non-current tabs.  This hover remains in place even after you change the class of the tab.  So, you hover over the tab, you click it, it changes to class `current` and then when you hover out, it fades back to opacity .3, despite the new class name;  You need do something to handle the hover for all tabs, even the current one.

If you change your hover code to this it should work:

```
$('ul.tabs a').hover(
    function () {
        if(!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", 1);
        }
    },
    function () {       
        if(!$(this).hasClass("current")) {
            $(this).fadeTo("fast", .3);
        }
    }
);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TLshW/

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks to you both. Great solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you remove the 'current' class right after you add it:

Added here:

```
$(this).addClass('current').
```

Removed here:

```
.find('a.current').removeClass('current')...
```

The .find will find the previous tab which already has class='current' as well as your clicked-tab which you just applied class='current'

Comment: Actually, this line should work because he is making a `sibling` call, so the removal does not affect `$(this)`.

Comment: @Jeff: Good catch! I love the fluent-syntax but it can get confusing after half a dozen calls!